# How to show Images after animation end in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

In my android application I have four imageviews when I click any one of that all(4) images are animating. I set the zoomout animation for all the images. once the animation is finished I am starting a new activity. The problem is once i click a back button The images(all the 4) images are hide. If I start a application from home screen the Images are showing. please anyone help me how to show the images once i click the back button

```
synopsis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //synopsis.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);
            synopsis.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
            team.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
            music.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
            gallery.startAnimation(animZoomOut);

            //synopsis.startAnimation(android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            animZoomOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Activity_Synopisis.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    });

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0" >
</scale>
```

Comment: when transiting to the new activity, clear all animations

Answer (score 0):

The activity is being recreated thus the animation result is gone, you either need to have some sort of preference or pass a variable in the bundle, when the activity after the animation loads, set the variable 'animation_finished' to true and then simply check in the oncreate of the imageview activity: if true: show/hide your images appropriately

Answer (score 0):

When the new activity is started, the old activity with the 4 images will remain in the state (i.e. with all images zoomed-out), so when you resume the old activity, you won't see that. One solution is to set the state of the 4 images to "normal" (i.e. show them) in the `onResume()` method of your old activity.

Answer (score 0):

As per your short note and my understanding,

intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Activity_Synopisis.class);
startActivity(intent);

synopsis.cancel();

team.cancel();

music.cancel();

gallery.cancel();

Try this one,It may help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer all.

I resolved this with the follo

```
synopsis.clearAnimation();
team.clearAnimation();
gallery.clearAnimation();
music.clearAnimation();
```

Added these above lines of code in Resume